# MegaDrupal MD.Foto: Module dependency displaying incompatibility status

Tags: 7

I've downloaded the MegaDrupal MD.Foto theme. The feature module for MD.Foto has a few dependencies. One of the dependancies is on Chaos Tools, which I loaded. After doing so, I noticed that the Panels module began displaying the incompatibility message:

Requires: Panels (disabled), Chaos tools (>=1.4) (incompatible with version 7.x-1.2)

What do I need to do to correct this?

Comment: The question contains the answer. Chaos Tools 7.x-1.2 is installed, but Panels requires a version equals or greater than 7.x-1.4. Therefore, the solution is to install a newer version of Chaos Tools.

Comment: @Pierre, Thanks for responding. That is what I thought at first, except the version I have loaded for Chaos Tools is the latest and greatest, which is 7.x-1.4 -- well, at least that is what it appears to be (https://drupal.org/project/ctools). Is it possible that there is a version variable that is whacked somewhere?

Comment: OK techies, -1 point hit for a *dumb* question or not, I am still looking for a way to understand how to determine what the conflict is. Anyone know how to get me there?

Comment: The conflict is clear, Drupal see a Ctools version < 7.x-1.4. If you think Drupal wrongly detect the installed CTools version, update and reformulate the question.

Comment: @Pierre, the only Panels and Chaos Tools modules I've downloaded and installed are the latest available--so if the module dubbed 7.x-1.4 for the download isn't, or is but hasn't something correctly, where do I look to determine what release it really is? Asked another way, what is Drupal looking at in order to make that determination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *think* Ctools 7.x-1.4 is the one you installed in your system and that Drupal wrongly detect it starts by clearing the cache. Then searh ctools.info file in your web root, if you find more than one, then you have duplicate installation of the Ctools module. Likely one of then is too old but is the one picked by Drupal. Remove it. If not, check the version in this file.

Comment: Alright, I see that I added another comment out there while you were typing this answer. Thank you. searching for the ctools.inof file in the web root is the answer I am looking for. Now, another dumb question, but a worthy one in terms of understanding how Drupal works--Can I expect to see other module installations in the web root with modulename.info?

Comment: For anyone following: I removed the old verison of the chaos tools dependency.